# Multiple tries of installing elementary fail

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install elementary both from a DVD and USB on multiple occasions. I  chose to boot from USB or DVD  it takes me to the main screen,  I chose install, then it starts loading 
A line of dots appear on the screen first and are joined with a bunch of white unidentifiable characters spanning the whole of the screen, like some kind of an error.

I keep waiting for something to happen and nothing does.

Tried it with mint as well.
Tried to re-download and reinstall on a different DVD and a different USB.

Same thing.

What do I do?

Will add a picture of the screen when I get back home.

Comment: Not really an answer here but I'm still lacking reputation points that would allow me to comment... A couple of questions: 1. Are you following the installation instructions found here: [elementary OS Installation](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) 2. Have you tried to run the Live environment rather than picking the install option at first boot? Maybe booting into the live environment then choosing to install will remedy the issue. 3. What app are you using to write the USB drive? That can make a difference in some cases. 4. Could you offer some information regarding the m

Comment: This sounds like a machine-specific problem. When you say "tried it with mint as well", does that mean that Mint also failed to install?

Comment: Yes.  Mint also experienced the same symptoms and failed to install.

Comment: To answer the questions.  1. Yes 2.yes, I tried doing the live environment on both mint and elementary and still the same problem.          
  3.i tried both Rufus and universal USB writer 4.ill get back on that later.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Rufus but I have had issues in the past burning a USB drive with something other than what is recommended by the OS makers. By using Rufus, I venture to guess you are burning the ISO to USB in Windows, correct? waldyrious is correct in the comment above that this seems like a machine specific deal. One thought, have you disabled SecureBoot in your BIOS settings? I never have mine enabled and I'm not sure if this could be an issue or not.

Comment: If both fail, then this indeed looks like a problem with your laptop rather than a particular distro/installer. You might have a better chance to get a solution on Unix&Linux or SuperUser. In fact, I'd suggest this question to be closed as off-topic (not specific to this Q&A site)

Comment: try burning your usb using Etcher https://etcher.io/ It's more reliable.